# How to filter list with Remaining days of date of birth in Django

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I want to display an upcoming birthday list with the remaining days of 30 days.
Example:

| Name | Date Of Birth | Remaining Days |
| --- | --- | --- |
| John Die | 2050-10-25 | 4 Days Left |
| John Snow | 2050-10-26 | 5 Days Left |

I don't know how to calculate the remaining days but I try this code but I got error "can't subtract offset-naive and offset-aware datetimes"

```py
customer=Customer.objects.filter()[:10]
    for i in customer:
        remaining = i.dateOfBirth - datetime.today()
        print(remaining)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can remove `tzinfo` from `datetime.today()`

```
remaining = i.dateOfBirth - datetime.today().replace(tzinfo=None)
```

Or add it to `i.dateOfBirth`

```
remaining = i.dateOfBirthreplace(tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc) - datetime.today()
```

More infos : https://code.luasoftware.com/tutorials/python/python-typeerror-cant-subtract-offset-naive-and-offset-aware-datetimes/